# Python json descobrir valor nulo

Tags: python, json, lista, null

Olá.

Estou com problemas na verificação de valor nulo em lista
Tenho um json, cujo trecho que me dá problema está abaixo:

```
{
    "id": "200827",
    "nome": "Emporio",
    "idPai": null,
    "nomePai": null
},
```

Entendi que se fizer o seguinte comando:

```
if lista[linha][coluna]:
```

o código a seguir só é executado se o valor for não nulo, porém não é o que acontece comigo. Estou tentando executar este trecho de código que não responde assim.

Só deve entrar no bloco se o valor da primeira coluna não for nulo.
Neste caso, testo o valor da terceira coluna e só me interessa os casos de valor nulo, porém a cláusula if nunca retorna false, embora na quinta iteração deveria cair no else, conrorme a lista de print's ao final.

```
if original[i][0]:
    if original[i][2]:
        print (original[i][2])
    else:
        executa tudo o que me interessa
        Jamais entra nesta parte do código
```

Saída do Print:

```
['200828']
['200827']
['200769']
['200769']
[None]
```

Temo que esteja cometendo algum erro muito básico, mas não estou conseguindo perceber qual seria.

Comment: Alano, você pode deixar o resto do código na pergunta ? Não acho que seja possível respondê-lo somente com o que você colocou.

Comment: foi possível responder sim, mas só por que tem a saída impressa daquele print ali. Senão teria que ter o código que lê o json, e um exemplo real de como está esse json aí.

Comment: mas sim, oq ue está acotnecendo, s eo JSON for esse aí mesmo, é que ele está sendo lido de forma errada pra dentro do Python. O uso de um número para acessar o valor, em vez das chaves `"id", "nome", ...` sugere que os dados não estão sendo importados para o Python da forma correta.

Comment: jsbueno já me resolveu o problema. Quanto ao uso de índices no lugar dos nomes das chaves, quis deixar o código mais genérico. Mas já repensei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu último valor, o que está em `original[i][0]` ainda não é o nulo (`None` em Python) - como você pode ver pelo que é impresso. O que é impresso é uma lista, com um único elemento, que ele sim é o `None`. O valor de `original[i][0]` é uma lista que tem pelo menos um elemento - o que, em testes do Python, tem valor `True`.

Se a estrutura for sempre essa, é só mudar o seu teste para:

```
if original[i][0]:
    if original[i][2][0]:
        print (original[i][2])
    else:
        # executa tudo o que me interessa
```